# Weird behaviour when running an INSERT command (C# and XLSX)

Tags: c#, sql, excel, insert

Somehow I cannot understand what is going on with a command I am using.
Basically I want to insert data into an EXCEL file as following:

```
string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=scriptsdb.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;ReadOnly=False;HDR=Yes;\"";
OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
string sSQLQuery = "INSERT INTO [Plan1$] ([ID], [NAME], [DESCRIPTION], [SQL_CODE]) VALUES ('" + NextID + "','" + txtbxName.Text + "','" + txtbxDescription.Text + "','" + txtboxSQL.Text + "')";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sSQLQuery, objConn);
objConn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now check it out. Sometimes it works (record is added) and sometimes I get an error message (Operation must use an updateable query).

As weird as it might sound I just get the error message when the Text fields have just one word. e.g: "TEST". As soon as I change it to "TEST ONE" it works fine. If I try to save it with two words right from the beginning it works.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: MODIFY permissions on the folder that the excel file is in.

Comment: Check the answer hopefully it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** change INSERT INTO [Plan1$] to INSERT INTO[Sheet1$].

Working code.

```
class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+"C:\\Users\\123\\Desktop\\plan1.xlsx;"+"Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;ReadOnly=False;HDR=Yes\";";
            // here you can use your text box or from
            // where ever you access the data to be inserted
            // into the that Excel file sheet

            string selectString = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] ([ID], [NAME], [DESCRIPTION], [SQL_CODE]) VALUES ('1','maziz','Not working','selectfrom you')";

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(selectString, con);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully inserted the records");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
               con.Close();
               con.Dispose();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```